# in line code for reporting p-values < .001 in r markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have been using the broman package with this in line code to pull p-values into my prose. Is there a way to update the in line code so that p-values of less than .001 are automatically reformatted to read "< .001" rather than the current output "= .000"?

```
library(broman)

m <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)
mdf <- data.frame(summary(m)$coefficients)

# transform into a clean function
names(mdf) [names(mdf) == 'Pr...t..'] <- 'p'
```

Cylinder count significantly predicts miles per gallon, *p* = `r myround(mdf["cyl","p"], 3)`.

Comment: `format.pval(mdf$p, eps = .001)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write a function like this:

```
myround2 <- function(x, digits = 3){
  if (x < 10^-digits) return(paste('<', 10^-digits))
  paste('=', myround(x, digits))
}
```

and use in place of `myround` in your markdown.

Comment: Thank you. I added a few more options in a reply below, but this was the start I needed.

Answer (score 1):

### inline_rename function

````
```{r inline_rename function}
# apply this function to clean up names of an lm object. 
# e.g.,  m <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars); m <- inline_rename(m) 
inline_rename <- function(x){  
  x <- data.frame(summary(x)$coefficients)
  names(x) [names(x) == 'Estimate'] <- 'Est'
  names(x) [names(x) == 'Pr...t..'] <- 'p'
  names(x) [names(x) == 'Std..Error'] <- 'SE'
  names(x) [names(x) == 't.value'] <- 't'     
  x
  }
```
````

### format_pval function

````
```{r format_pval function}
library(broman) # for myround function

format_pval <- function(x){
  if (x < .001) return(paste('<', '.001'))
  if (x > .250) return(paste('>', '.250'))
  paste('=', myround(x, 3))   # 3 = no. of digits to round p value to if .001 < p < .250.
}
````

```

### Create some regression models to pull stats from

````
```{r create some regression models to pull stats from}
m <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + wt  + qsec + vs + am + gear, mtcars)
m <- inline_rename(m)
```
````

Weight significantly predicts mpg, ${\beta}$ = `r myround(m["wt","Est"], 2)`, *p* `r format_pval(m["wt","p"])`.
Gear count does not significantly predict mpg, ${\beta}$ = `r myround(m["gear","Est"], 2)`, *p* `r format_pval(m["gear","p"])`.

````
```{r}
m <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)
m <- inline_rename(m)
```
````

Horse power significantly predicts mpg, ${\beta}$ = `r myround(m["hp","Est"], 2)`, *p* `r format_pval(m["hp","p"])`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a particular way I like my p-values formatted, so I wrote my own function to handle it all at once.  I bring it up here only because `format.pval` seems pretty rigid in what it will format (meaning, it seems it will do the same format for all values, where I prefer some values to be rounded to two decimal places and some to three).  If `format.pval` doesn't fit your exact needs, it isn't difficult to write your own function.

```
set.seed(pi)
p_very_large <- runif(10, .98, 1)
p_large <- runif(10, .10, .98)
p_small <- runif(10, .001, .10)
p_very_small <- runif(10, 1e-7, 1e-3)

cbind(format.pval(p_very_large, eps = .001, digits = 3),
      pixiedust::pvalString(p_very_large))

cbind(format.pval(p_large, eps = .001, digits = 3),
      pixiedust::pvalString(p_large))

cbind(format.pval(p_small, eps = .001, digits = 3),
      pixiedust::pvalString(p_small))

cbind(format.pval(p_very_small, eps = .001, digits = 3),
      pixiedust::pvalString(p_very_small))
```